# Windows phone native debug doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I have C# Windows Phone 8 project and WinRT component. I want to debug native code in WinRT component. I've set Native only in project properties but it still can't stop on break point in native code

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running this native code?

Comment: What Paul said, are you sure that this code is being invoked at some point?

Comment: of course. I'am writing Unit tests for my WinRT component.

Comment: So what exactly made you sure that it got loaded?  What are you looking at?  What does the Debug + Windows + Modules window say?  Document your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found reason of problem. I've tried to debug my application from unit test app. It is not allowed, in common windows phone 8 application all work normally

Answer (score 0):

You must select native debugger in your project properties.

In fact you can only debug managed **or** native code. But not both at the same times.
Look more information [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/C++_support_from_Windows_Phone_8#Debugger)

Comment: Debugger which doesn't works on native code with a mixed code on WP8 appear generally when the wrong debugger is selected. Other possibility could be winPRT component is not reference or use debugger with release.

Comment: it's selected. But managed breakpoints still work( Native break points is not work

Comment: You have select the native debugger in the project property (look the link to confirm) but you always debug managed code? Which version of VS do you use? You try to debug with a device or an emulator?

Comment: Yes, I've selected native debugger. I use VS2013 and try with device and emulator

Comment: The winPrt project is a part of your solution? How have you referenced your component? (I'haven't vs2013 to check)